# Refresh div contents without reloading page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web page with JavaScript and HTML5. I wrote some code that adds text to a div.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            var newGame = document.getElementById('playerStats');
            newGame.innerHTML += 'Name: ' + getPlayerName() + '<br/>';
            newGame.innerHTML += 'Class: ' + getPlayerClass() + '<br/>';
            newGame.innerHTML += 'Level: ' + getPlayerLevel() + '<br/>';
            newGame.innerHTML += 'XP: ' + getPlayerXP() + ' / ' + needXP[getPlayerLevel()];
</script>
```

Now let's say that the player's XP has changed. I don't want to have to reload the page to see the new XP. I want the div displaying the player stats to refresh immediately, without a page reload. Any ideas?

P.S.: Using `load()` isn't the best solution. I tried that already and it's not working as it should (the div becomes smaller and weird things happen).

Update: I did something like this right now, but is there a better approach?

```js
function updateStats(){
    var newGame = document.getElementById('playerStats');
    newGame.innerHTML = '';
    newGame.innerHTML += 'Name: ' + getPlayerName() + '<br/>';
    newGame.innerHTML += 'Class: ' + getPlayerClass() + '<br/>';
    newGame.innerHTML += 'Level: ' + getPlayerLevel() + '<br/>';
    newGame.innerHTML += 'XP: ' + getPlayerXP() + ' / ' + needXP[getPlayerLevel()];
}

function addXP() {
    player.XP++;
    if(player.XP >= needXP[getPlayerLevel()]){
        player.Level++;
        player.XP = 0;
        alert('Level UP!');
    }
    store.set('player', { Name: getPlayerName(), Class: getPlayerClass(), Level: getPlayerLevel(), XP: player.XP });
    updateStats();
}
```

Comment: Wrap this code inside a function and you can call it anytime you want.

Comment: That's what I just did, but I'll have to work with additional function everytime i change something. Can be annoying.

Comment: well that's how it is done :)

Comment: @Oen44 Are you happy with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have a function that gets each data point that appears in `newGame`: `getPlayerXP`, `getPlayerLevel`, and so on. You can write a corresponding set of functions to set each data point. For example:

```
function setPlayerXP(player, xp) {
  player.xp = xp;
  updateStats();
}
```

By including a call to `updateStats()`,  you ensure that `newGame` gets updated when necessary. Now make sure that you use `setPlayerXP` whenever you want to assign a new value to that player attribute.